# Cancel button on lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Need one cancel button on lightning component. 
Case 1)- If we edit the existing record then cancel button should redirect to 'Detail Page' of record

Case 2) - If we are creating new record but want to cancel it without saving then it should redirect to listview page.

Note: We are using same component for both New Record and Edit Record.

Comment: Hello, What have you tried to meet these requirements? Any place where you need help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the JavaScript method for your cancel button (use context specific if - eg : If ID exists then it is edit, or else new).
Use below event to redirect to Detail Page :

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
  "recordId": "Pass the Record Id of budget record Here",
  "slideDevName": "related"
});
navEvt.fire();
```

Similarly below event to redirect to List View :

```
var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");
navEvent.setParams({
            "listViewId": listviews.Id,
            "listViewName": null,
            "scope": "Contact"
        });
navEvent.fire();
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks Ajinkya